# Select ROI of an Image/video frame in Flask

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, flask, image-processing

I am trying to figure out a way to crop out a  region from the first frame of `cv2.videocapture()` to run the contour detection on just that part. I am able to achieve this via `cv2.selectROI` for my desktop but want help with doing the same thing (user could select ROI on their own) on Flask.

As if right now, the final output of the analysis is showing on the web URL (I used the classic buffer-to-byte for this) but the selection of the Region of Interest still happens as a cv2 output window.

Need a way wherein the user can select and crop region on their own on the flask web url

Comment: that is completely a user-side, i.e. javascript, task

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you edit the question to add some of your existing code? This will help others discover this issue and give a tailored answer. As mentioned above, this might well be a front-end task, but the implementation would largely depend on what you already have.

Comment: Hi @Utkarsh Pandey, Did you find any solution for this?